# Calling method from arraylist

Tags: java

Say I have an arraylist `performActions` with values "openURL" and "closeBrowser". Both these values (openURL and closeBrowsers) and methods are in a different class.

How do I call these methods by getting the value from `performActions` arraylist?

To be specific: If I do `performAction.get(0)` the "openURL" method should be executed.

Comment: By values, I assume you mean strings containing "openURL" and "closeBrowser". In this case, there is no way, this isn't PHP! Look into using interfaces to create pseudo function pointers.

Comment: There is actually a way to call a method given the method name in Java. But I would first like to know: Why on earth??? I think you should redesign your code.

Comment: Use Polymorphism :  for example an interface called: Action  and two classes UrlOpener and BrowserCloser implements it by redefining execute() method from Action

Comment: You need to be clear what types of object you are dealing with. Are you storing Method objects (which is fairly unusual thing to do in Java) or some other objects that forward calls to the eventual implementation? It would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no *easy* way to do what you describe (you could use reflection but I would advise against it). You can, however, store a set of integers and then use those integers as 'codes' for performing various functions. This would be somewhat analogous to storing the methods themselves.

```
public void runMethod(int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            // do something (e.g. run a certain method)
            break;
        case 2:
            // do something else (e.g. run another method)
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

So in your case, `openURL` could perhaps be represented by `1` and `closeBrowser` by `2` (you could of course use any two integers). You would then store these values in an `ArrayList<Integer>`, after which you would loop through your list and call a method like `runMethod` on each value, thereby performing your desired method.

**Edit**: If your methods require an argument, you could always employ a similar concept using `Map`s instead of `ArrayList`s, mapping an integer (representing a method) to its argument.

Comment: Are you against reflection in general or in this specific case? In this specific case, I agree.

Comment: Well most of the time there are ways to avoid having to use reflection (this is one of them). Having said that, I can see how on some rare occasions it could potentially come in handy. So I'm not against it in general, I just think that it's overkill often times.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and use string comparison to execute your methods:

```
List<String> items; // from Excel

for (String item : items) {
    // for example, item might be: openURL("www.google.com")

    if (item.startsWith("openURL(")) {
        // parse out the actual url
        String url = item.replaceAll(".*\"(.*)\".*", "$1");
        openURL(url);
    } else if (item.startsWith("closeURL(")) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection.

Eg : 
    Method method = getClass().getMethod(yourarraylist.get(0));
    method.invoke(this);

This is similar to what we do while loading jdbc drivers class.forName();

i suggest reading about reflection. 
Hipe this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `ArrayList` contains [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), and the method is static, you can use [Method.invoke(null, null)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)

If the method reference is not static, then you need to provide some context in order to execute it.

I would wrap the `Method` and `Object` on which it is to executed in a wrapper class and provide an invoke/execute method...

```
public class ProxyMethod {
    private Method method;
    priavte Object instance;

    public ProxyMethod(Object instance, Method method) {
        this.instance = instance;
        this.method = method;
    }

    public void invoke() {
        method.invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Now you can also supply parameters as well, if you need to...

```
public class ProxyMethod {
    // Previous decelerations...

    private Object[] parameters;

    public ProxyMethod(Object instance, Method method, Object... parameters) {
        this(instance, methd);
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public void invokeWith() {
        method.invoke(this, parameters);
    }

    public void invokeWith(Object... parameters) {
        method.invoke(this, parameters);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a scripting language :

- You have JavaScript Rhino built-in in Java 6
- You can call Groovy code
- You can use simple expression language interpreter like e.g. MVEL
- You can parse your notation by youself if there are only 2 functions